# Weakly lower-semicontinuous functional on $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, periodic-functions, semicontinuous-functions

I am interested in the following problem:

Is there any function (let's say continuous) $W:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying
$W(x+1)=W(x) \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ and such that the functional
$L^2([0,1])\to \mathbb{R},\ f\mapsto \int_{0}^1 W(f(x))dx$,
is weakly lower-semicontinuous?
.
Of course, $W=cons$ is possible but I am looking for other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not other functions. If $f \mapsto \int W(f) \ dx$ is weakly lower semicontinuous from $L^2$ to $\mathbb R$ then $W$ is convex. Due to the periodicity requirements, only constant functions qualify.

---

Assume $W$ is not convex. Then there are $v_1,v_2$ and $\lambda\in (0,1)$ with $W(\lambda v_1+ (1-\lambda v_2)) > \lambda W(v_1) +  (1-\lambda)W(v_2)$.

We will now construct an oscillating sequence: Define
$\phi(x):=  \chi_{[0,\lambda)}v_1 + \chi_{[\lambda,1)}v_2$ and extend it $1$-periodically to a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.
Define $u_n(x) := \phi(nx)$, $x\in (0,1)$.
Then
$$
\int_0^1 W(u_n) = \lambda W(v_1) + (1-\lambda)W(v_2).
$$
The sequence $(u_n)$ converges weakly in $L^2$ to the constant function $u(x)=\lambda v_1+(1-\lambda)v_2$. And
$$
\int_0^1 W(u) = W(\lambda v_1+(1-\lambda)v_2)> \lambda W(v_1) + (1-\lambda)W(v_2) = \int_0^1 W(u_n).
$$
And $u\mapsto \int W(u)$ is not weakly lower semicontinuous.

Comment: Oh really? How to prove that $W$ must be convex? That does not look obvious to me and it is interesting.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro added a short proof of this claim

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!