# Convex Lagrangian prevents oscillations - why?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convex-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

We are given an interval $I \subset \mathbb{R},$ the space of $q-$absolutely continuous functions $AC^q(I,\mathbb{R}^{n})$ which satisfy continuity of the function and the existence of its $q-$integrable weak derivative.

Let $F: AC^q(I,\mathbb{R}^{n}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, F(\gamma) = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} L(\gamma(t), \dot{\gamma}(t))dt$ be a functional on $AC^q(I, \mathbb{R}^{n})$ with $\gamma \in AC^q(I, \mathbb{R}^{n}), t_0, t_1 \in I.$

I saw in different sources that convexity of the Lagrangian $L: \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in the argument of the derivative $\dot{\gamma}(t)$ ensures the minimizing curve $\gamma$ does not "oscillate itself to death" in the attempt to minimize the functional.

Why does convexity prevent oscillations? Any intuition and complete proof or reference to one will be appreciated.

Comment: see this q&a https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4855533/weakly-lower-semicontinuous-functional-on-l2/4855565#4855565 for the discussion of the effect of non-convexity

Comment: Thank you, that's enlightening. Your answer gives an answer to my question when $L$ only depends on $\dot{\gamma}$ and $q=2.$ Do these $u_n$ also converge weakly in $L^p$ for $p \neq 2?$ And how should I construct a sequence like this when $L$ also depends on $\gamma?$

Comment: These examples also work for $q\ne 2$. If $\dot\gamma_n$ is oscillating, then usually $\gamma_n$ converges strongly.

Comment: What is still unclear to me: The weak lower semi-continuity ensures that a minimizer exists, at least for the case that the functional is also coercive and continuous. However, how does the weak lower semi-continuity (or the convexity of the Lagrangian) ensure that the minimizer is not the limit of some sequence with oscillating $\dot{\gamma_n}?$

Comment: If the minimizer exists, it does not matter whether it is the limit of an oscillating sequence.  These oscillating sequences are a technique to show that certain problems have no minimizers.

Comment: Thank you, I reread the examples in my script again and that's exactly how these sequences are used.